# Adding nested values using JsonPath in Java

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I'm using [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) in Java, and I'd like to know if there's a way to use the path specifications to add nested values. The following example will clarify.

I have this json

```
{"attr1":"value1"}
```

Since I need to work on the json a lot, and I do not want to parse it every time (according to the [documentation](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#reading-a-document)), I load the json in the following way

```
String sJson = "{\"attr1\":\"value1\"}"
Object json = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().jsonProvider().parse(sJson);
```

and I'd like to add a value so that the final json is

```
{"attr1":"value1","attr2":{"nested_attr1":"nested_value1"}}
```

What's the best way to add `attr2` to obtain that result? Is there a way in which I can use the JsonPath syntax (`attr2.nested_value1`)?

If I use

```
Configuration.defaultConfiguration().jsonProvider().setProperty(json, "attr2.nested_attr1", "nested_value1");
```

what I obtain is an updated json like

```
{"attr1":"value1","attr2.nested_attr1":"nested_value1"}
```

and this because `setProperty` do not work with paths. I tried using

```
JsonPath.parse(json).put("$", "attr2.nested_attr1", "nested_value1"").jsonString();
```

but yet I have to parse the json every time back and forth, and second I obtain the same result as before. Is there a way to handle this problem, or do I have to implement the nested add by myself?